# int to textbox.text with C#

Tags: c#

With VB I have no error with this method

```
Private Sub But_Leer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles But_Leer.Click

    Dim INT(3) As Integer
    ProEasy.ReadDevice32("LT4000_1.#INTERNAL", "Valor1", INT, 1)
    TextBox1.Text = INT(0)
```

But with C#, I have an error when assigning "Valor" int to Textbox1.text. A string is required:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] Valor = new int[3];
        ProEasy.ReadDevice32("LT4000_1.PLC1", "MWO", out Valor, 1);
        textBox1.Text = **Valor**[0];
```

Anyone knows why? I just starting with VB and C# language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Valor[0]` returns `int`, you need to convert it to `string`

```
textBox1.Text = Valor[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Text` property of the `TextBox` control requires a `string`. Valor is an array containing integer values. Therefore you will have to cast that value to string.

```
textBox1.Text = Valor[0].ToString();
```